# Origine del concetto di americanata

Tags: word-usage, etymology

[Americanata](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/americanata) è un sostantivo che si usa spesso col significato di:

> - 1905; (iron. o spreg.,)  cosa, azione o avvenimento caratterizzato da grandiosità ed esagerazione, secondo quello che si ritiene essere il gusto americano: *la sua festa di matrimonio è stata una vera americanata.*

Ho sempre pensato che il termine  avesse avuto origine con il cinema americano dove spesso si vedono azioni incredibili e volutamente esagerate, ma il De Mauro riporta come data  il 1905, ben prima della diffusione dell'industria cinematografica.

Qual è il periodo e soprattutto il contesto da cui l'espressione “americanata” ha avuto origine?

Comment: Ah, interessante, anch'io l'avrei ritenuto più recente. Pqcv, lo Zingarelli lo fa risalire addirittura al 1890.

Comment: Non ho tempo per approfondire, ma mi sembra che qualche spunto possa venire cercando “americanata” in Google Books e restringendo la ricerca a testi dell'Ottocento: qualcosa c'è, e sembra anche curioso: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22americanata%22&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899

Comment: @DaG In una delle citazioni si legge “La cosa sembra un po' americana o, come dicono comunemente i francesi un'americanata”. Possibile che venga dal francese?

Comment: @egreg: Ah, interessante. Di affine trovo solo [*américainerie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/am%C3%A9ricainerie) e [*américonnerie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/am%C3%A9riconnerie), più esplicito ma soprattutto troppo recente (lo attribuiscono al 1920). Chissà.

Answer (score 2):

Il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* riporta le [prime attestazioni delle diverse accezioni](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000007.jpg) di un termine. Alla [voce "americanata" che si trova nel Supplemento del 2009](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_Pagina_026.jpg) possiamo vedere che la prima attestazione del vocabolo col significato di

> Azione, idea, ecc. eccentrica, bizzarra,
> strana, fuori dalle regole

è questa citazione di *Torre di guardia* di Alberto Savinio ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00260.jpg)] e  [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00260.jpg)]):

> Questa notizia fa parte delle cosiddette 'americanate'. Americanata è l'espressione dell"eccessivo' americano.

Come si spiega sul [sito web di Gian­franco Fran­chi](https://www.gianfrancofranchi.com/torre-di-guardia/), si tratta di una raccolta a cura di Sciascia di articoli di Savinio per la rubrica con lo stesso nome del giornale *La Stampa*:

> “Torre di guardia” era il nome di una rubrica curata da Savinio per “La Stampa” tra il 1934 e il 1940; Sciascia ha raccolto buona parte di quelle pagine – escludendo quelle apparse nella “Nuova Enciclopedia”, con poche eccezioni, e quelle “macchiate” da un comunque perplesso apprezzamento per il fascismo: peccato, potevano rivelarsi affascinanti – e ha curato questa edizione Sellerio, 1977, raffinata da una pregevole introduzione di Salvatore Battaglia.

Quindi, questo uso del vocabolo "americanata" sembra essere nato nell'ambito giornalistico.

Tuttavia, ricercando ["americanata" su Google Libri](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22americanata%22&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&cad=h), si trovano alcune attestazioni a partire dalla fine dell'Ottocento. Una delle più antiche che sono riuscita a trovare è un'edizione del 1888 del libro [*Eco d'America* di Giuseppe Sormani](https://books.google.es/books?id=KRX7NKgskpYC&q=%22americanata%22&dq=%22americanata%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik-eGch5vqAhWzAWMBHRXkBbg4ChDoATAFegQIARAg) in cui si può leggere questo passaggio, che ci fa capire che il vocabolo era già in uso:

> Il vocabolo « americanata » è un barbaro sostantivo non ancora registrato in alcun glossario. Nondimeno è voce consacrata dall'uso per dinotare cosa strabiliante, non disgiunta da una certa dose di ciarlatanismo. In attesa, dunque, che i nostri accademici riparino alla dimenticanza, dobbiamo intanto convenire che il senso di pagliacciata che ne costituisce il fondo gli è propriamente devoluto: atteso che è dall'America che ci sono giunte delle portentose fandonie che hanno fatto divenire quel paese la favola del mondo.

Anche su questo giornaletto intitolato [*Letture di famiglia*](https://books.google.es/books?id=dVeRyxGVZ9EC&q=%22americanata%22&dq=%22americanata%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSp8f2jJvqAhWmC2MBHREvDbs4FBDoATADegQIARAS), del 1884, appare il termine "americanata" parecchie volte, in questo caso in un contesto che sembra anche giornalistico. Ecco un esempio:

> A Parigi sembra che abbia fatto fortuna un'*americanata*, seppure la faccenda non finirà a bastonate. 
>       Un branco di speculatori, fra cui dicesi vi sia quel Gordon Bennet arcimilionario, che è proprietario del *New-York Herald*, si sono messi d'accordo per pubblicare nella metropoli della blague un giornale politico senza opinioni o piuttosto [...].

D'accordo con lo stesso dizionario sopra citato, "americanata" può significare anche

> Ciò che denota cattivo gusto, volgarità.

Secondo questa fonte, la prima attestazione di "americanata" con questo significato è questa citazione tratta dal libro *Panopticon romano* di Mario Praz, pubblicato nel 1967:

> Quei giardini pensili degli antichi, almeno come li immaginano con fantasia da pubblicità alberghiera gl'illustratori dei libri per fanciulli, sanno troppo d'americanata.